# How can I replace a ksqlDB table while keeping the same state store?

Tags: ksqldb

Using Confluent's ksqlDB 5.5.1 (which relates to ksqlDB 0.7.1 I think), I created an aggregated table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE xxx WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'xxx') AS
SELECT xxx
FROM xxx
GROUP BY xxx
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Let's say I have to add attribute yyy to query. I have to `DROP` the table and re-create it. But in doing so, a new state is created and I lose all the old aggregated value.

One workaround would be to have infinite retention and re-create the table with `'auto.offset.reset'='earliest'` but I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't involve infinite retention.

Any idea? It would be great to be able to do `REPLACE TABLE xxx AS ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but is being worked on: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/design-proposals/klip-28-create-or-replace.md